# Controller Chokes on Nested Model's Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

*I'm using Rails 4 + Ruby 2*

Nested models in Rails are a huge pain. There, I said it.

Okay, so I have an `entry` model with `approaches` nested inside.

```
# --- entry.rb ---
has_many :approaches, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :approaches, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:approach_type].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

The approach parameters come over to the controller's `create` method like this (from the log):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"entry"=>{
  "aircraft_registration"=>"N384HA", 
  "flight_date"=>"2013-12-10", 
  "departure"=>"KSAD", 
  ...
 
  "approaches"=>{
    "1386633324306"=>{
      "approach_type"=>"GLS", 
      "holding"=>"false", 
      "quantity"=>"2", 
      "airport"=>"FFS", 
      "runway"=>"12L", 
      "updated_flag"=>"true"
    }, 
    "1386633813852"=>{
      "approach_type"=>"TACAN", 
      "holding"=>"false", 
      "quantity"=>"1", 
      "airport"=>"DFD", 
      "runway"=>"12L", 
      "updated_flag"=>"true"
    }
  },  
}
```

For testing purposes, I do blanket param allowance:

```
params.require(:entry).permit!
```

...and I get this error from Satan himself:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Approach(#70114475640640) expected, 
got Array(#70114477494560)
```

It seems that the problem is that the Entry model doesn't like the approaches being an array (which actually looks like a hash with id numbers, but what do I know).

### My Question

**How should the params look on a nested model when they come over from the view to the controller?**

I'm trying to narrow down whether I have mis-formatted data coming from my form, or a problem in my controller.

I'm new to Rails, so please be gentle. :)

Comment: It's kind of funny that you ask us to be gentle when you started the question stating that "it's a pain" :)

Comment: Haha... yeah, I'm just playing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, a nested model should come through something like this:

```
params = {
  :entry => {
    :approaches_attributes => [
      {:approach_one_attr => ...}, 
      {:approach_two_attr => ...}
    ]
  }
}
```

Looks to me like the problem here is with the form in your view not the controller.